# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in git

Tags: git

I have a problem when pushing git. 
this error message shows up:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: Hi Carles - the other question linked above has several possible solutions to your question.  If none of those solve your problem then a new question that explains the unique properties of your circumstances would be helpful.  :)

Comment: I was facing the same error message and the thread at https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/9293 got me to try the command `git config --global http.sslbackend schannel` which resolved the issue.

Comment: I solved the issues in VS 2019 going to Git Global Settings and changing Cryptographic Network Provider from "Unset" to "Secure Channel"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways this issue has been resolved previously:

A. Ensure the root cert is added to `git.exe`'s certificate store as discussed here.

B. Tell Git where to find the CA bundle by running:

```
git config --system http.sslCAPath /absolute/path/to/git/certificates
```

or copying the CA bundle to the `/bin` directory and adding the following to the `gitconfig` file:

```
sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

C. Reinstalling Git.

D. Ensuring that the complete CA is present, including the root cert.

Comment: Can also try using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54218725/4941386