# Git Bash Client for windows not able to clone github repository for a project

Tags: github, devops

i am trting to clone a source code for a project from github but i am getting the below error

Cloning into 'vprofile-project'...
fatal: Unsupported SSL backend 'schannelcd'. Supported SSL backends:
openssl
schannel

it is a simple copy and paste code that should run once copied on terminal.
i have tired to run it in a new directory but nothing changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210531/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to resolve the issue by removing the multiple values in the GIT configurations.the below code sorts the issue

git config --global --replace-all http.sslBackend openssl

OR

git config --global --replace-all http.sslBackend